# Swap_Image function not working properly

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

hello everyone  i am developing a web appliacation using netbeans and Mysql and apache tomcat server. i am using jsp files. for some purpose i have written code like

```
  <TBODY>
                        <TR vAlign=top>
                        <TD width=15 height="23"><IMG height=19 src="images/r1_107.gif" 
                    width=15></TD>

                          <TD width=50><div align="center"><a 
                    onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image21','','images/home_207.gif',1)" 
                    onMouseOut=MM_swapImgRestore() 
                    href="newjsp.jsp"><img 
                    height=19 src="images/home_107.gif" width=50 
                    border=0 name=Image21></a></div></TD>
```

But swap image function is not working. will you explian me what swap image function does and whats wrong in my code. i am having some trouble with MM_swapimage function jst explian me function and its argument

Answer (score 1):

where is the code for the javascript function swap_image() ?

it is not possible to answer unless you show the swap_image function.

Comment: i have enclosed code in it self ... code is like   onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image21','','images/home_207.gif',1)" 
onMouseOut=MM_swapImgRestore()

Comment: i have home_207.gif image in my images folder. but i do not have Image21. will you please explain me what is that Image21??

Answer (score 0):

Well the code you pasted was not very distinct. What exactly you want to do?

If you want to change the image's src using javascript, do the following-

```
<img src="image123.gif" id="topImage" onclick="changeImageSource(this, 'images/img21.gif')"/>
```

And on javascript side,

```
function changeImageSource(imgElement, newImageSource) {
    imgElement.src = newImageSource;
}
```

Comment: i want that images should change when i roll mouse over & out of images. for this i am using jsp pages in netbeans